# Tablet App for Sketching Technical Concepts

Tags: drawing-tablet, sketching

I'm a software developer looking for some sketching app for a tablet.
In my daily business I need to sketch a lot of technical concepts. Instead of composing them out of a palette of predefined shapes I want to draw them with a pencil on a tablet and let the app recognize certain shape patterns and smooth them.

What I expect the app to do is:

- Smooth straight lines
- Connect line ends close to each other ( to ease sketching rectangles)
- recognize block letters and allow editing them as text (no formatting or such stuff)
- align elements relative to each other's bounds, centers, etc.
- allow moving elements or groups of them
- allow scaling elements or groups of them
- Recognize circles, arrows, rectangles, squares, etc. and smooth them
- Allow the creation of template shapes for reuse
- Extend rectangles, circles, custom shapes, etc. so that a certain text fits into it

Does anyone know about such an app?

Any hint will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention what tablet you want to do this on, but as far as IOS and Android go, I'm pretty sure there is nothing available that will handle all your requirements set out above. However, if you wait until June, Adobe will launch a pen and ruler that will work with most apps and should deliver what you need.

You can see theme here... http://blogs.adobe.com/conversations/2013/05/adobe-xd-explores-the-analog-future.html